# Reciprocal roots

Tags: polynomials

I have this question:

> It is known that two of the roots of the equation $3x^3+x^2-kx+6=0$ are reciprocals of each other. What is the value of $k$?

How do I find $k$?

Comment: What did you try? What do you know?

Comment: Let's assume that the root is $x_0$. Then we want that $x_2 = \frac{1}{x_0}$ is also a root. What equation does this then give to you?

Comment: Are you able to work out the product of the roots, XxM?

Comment: Happy with answer of Hoppe, XxM?

Answer (score 2):

We know that $-6/3=x_1x_2x_3=1\cdot x_3$, hence $x=-2$ is a root.   Now plug in.

PS: The other roots are $\frac16(5\pm i\sqrt{11})$.

Comment: Right idea, but note that the problem has a leading coefficient $\neq 1$ on the highest power of $x$.

Comment: You’re right, I’ve edited.